# parsing a httparty get response in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, api, parsing

I can't figure out how to parse this response. I'm only trying to extract one single count from this.

UPDATE:
How can I parse this XML response?

Here's my API connection information

I'm using Ruby irb, with HTTParty

```
require 'httparty'

api_key = "6e569b3d-3457-9485-edb2-eccd27272dbf"
secret_key = "MDVkYTQzMDgtOWRiOC04NDULTRkYWUtODQwOTc5ZDFkZTQ3NTZhOG1NWQtNmMzMi0xYjE0LWYMzgtNDc0YzU0MWYxYmUx"

def urlncode(string)
  URI.escape(string, Regexp.new("[Generating an API Signature^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))
end

salt = rand(10000000000).to_s

hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', secret_key, salt)

signature = urlncode(Base64.encode64(hash))

# controller / action
api_path = "/Tickets/TicketCount"

url = "http://support.myorganization.org/api/index.php?e=#{api_path}"

response = HTTParty.get("#{url}&apikey=#{api_key}&salt=#{salt}&signature=#{signature}").parsed_response
```

My response: (truncated)

```
response = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<ticketcount>\n<departments>\n<department id=\"0\">\n<totalitems><![CDATA[11]]></totalitems>\n<lastactivity><![CDATA[1423657406]]></lastactivity>\n<totalunresolveditems><![CDATA[11]]></totalunresolveditems>\n<ticketstatus id=\"1\" lastactivity=\"1423657406\" totalitems=\"6\" />\n<ticketstatus id=\"2\" lastactivity=\"1422566730\" totalitems=\"5\" />\n<tickettype id=\"1\" lastactivity=\"1423657406\" totalitems=\"11\" totalunresolveditems=\"11\" />\n<ownerstaff id=\"0\" lastactivity=\"1423657406\" totalitems=\"7\" totalunresolveditems=\"7\" />\n<ownerstaff id=\"4\" lastactivity=\"1420825202\" totalitems=\"2\" totalunresolveditems=\"2\" />\n<ownerstaff id=\"17\" lastactivity=\"1422452400\" totalitems=\"1\" totalunresolveditems=\"1\" />\n<ownerstaff id=\"26\" lastactivity=\"1422566730\" totalitems=\"1\"
```

When I try to do:

```
response['ticket count']
```

I get this: (which is obviously not all the data included)

```
irb(main):029:0> data['ticketcount']
=> "ticketcount"
```

Comment: you're not calling the right endpoint, your response is XML not json.  check the endpoint you're hitting

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more; not sure what you mean by endpoint

Comment: You're trying to go to something like `http://support.myorganization.org/api/index.php?e=/Tickets/TicketCount` right?

Comment: correct, with the api info in URL parameters. if XML shouldn't i be able to **data = response.parsed_response** and then **data['ticketcount']**?

Comment: it's XML not json, you can't parse XML into json

Comment: fair enough. I'll update my question. how can I parse the XML?